# Modify CreationDate for TFS Changeset

Tags: tfs, migration, changeset

I'm currently creating a migration tool from one version control system to TFS and am using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` assembly and have run into a problem.  I am able to mimic the changes for each `Changeset`, but the `CreationDate` property is automatically generated by the `CheckIn` method as shown below:

```
var changeSetId = workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, userName, comment, note, null, null);
```

I am then able to load the `Changeset` object by ID that was returned by the `CheckIn` method:

```
var changeSet = workspace.VersionControlServer.GetChangeset(changeSetId);
```

I am attempting to set the `CreationDate` (not readonly) in the `Changeset` and I am able to do that via the following code:

```
changeSet.CreationDate = legacyLog.Date;
changeSet.Update();
```

But, after calling the `Update` method, the changes are not saved on the server as I have attempted to verify the date in the browser and it still shows today's date as the `CreationDate` (unless I'm misunderstanding where that date is displayed/rendered).  Has anyone attempted to change the `CreationDate` for a `Changeset` before or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: I know you can modify them in the database, but it's not supported and could cause some unexpected issues - I had to modify 1 or 2 changeset dates after the server lost its time settings and went into the future :)

Comment: Did the dates show up correctly in the web interface of TFS after the date change?

Comment: Not sure about the Web, but in VS they were correct I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with DaveShaw, you need to directly modify changeset's check-in time in TFS database. SQL statement: UPDATE tbl_Changeset SET CreationDate='?' WHERE ChangeSetId='?'

Please check the ModifyCheckinDate2012 source code on this link for the details: https://tfsprod.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

However, be note that it is not recommended to modify directly in TFS database, as this may bring some potential risks.

Comment: I did try it and all looks good.  Thanks for the tips Vicky and @DaveShaw

Comment: This is VERY dangerous as the database makes implicit use of the fact that all changeset numbers are in chronological order.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the Changeset date is **TOTALLY UNSUPPORTED**. The TFVC server object ensures that changesets are always created in chronological order and makes a few assumptions based on this assurance.

History, sparse storage and reporting also make use of this cardinal rule. It's also one of the reasons why it's still not possible to merge two team projects from different collections.

I checked with the product team to be sure, their response:

> Yes, we certainly make that assumption in the TFVC code.

So when changing a date, there are a number of not publicly documented rules that must be taken into account. Otherwise your database could fail to upgrade in the future or won't be able to be imported into VSTS when you way to make the jump.

If you need to make these changes, the best solution is to contact Microsoft Support so that they provide you with a script that performs the correct consistency checks.