# Can I set different CreationDate of Changeset after check-in into TFVC - TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs, migration, tfvc

I faced with problem I can't modify CreationDate of Changeset in TFS 2015
use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll

```
    $changeset = $versionControlServer.GetChangeset("2656")
    $changeset.CreationDate = $(get-date).AddDays(-90)
    $changeset.Comment = "bla-bla-bla"
    $changeset.Owner = "test\test1"
    $changeset.Committer = "test\test1"
    $changeset.CommitterDisplayName = "test\test1"
    $changeset.OwnerDisplayName = "test\test1"

    $changeSet.Update()
```

After attempting run the `$changeSet.Update()` method, the result was not good. Only `$changeset.Comment = "bla-bla-bla"` was applied, other properties weren't  success.

So, my questions are :

1. How can I modify properties `CreationDate, Committer` and etc. without the direct intervention into the database
2. Why this properties are only read?
3. Maybe some policy is prevent me do it?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do change the check-in date?

The API isn't going to let you do it and editing the TFS SQL database directly is unsupported.  If you decide to do it anyway then there is a fairly high probability that you will break something so make sure you have a current backup.

That said, there is a similar question here: [Modify CreationDate for TFS Changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223958/modify-creationdate-for-tfs-changeset)

Comment: I have git repository with commits since 2009.
So, main goal of that move it all from Git to Tfvc.
I use Git-tf tool. It works fine except I can't  retain original date of commits. I have managed to keep chronology of commits and users but original date no.

Comment: @SAP You can push your Git repo directly into TFS (assuming you're using TFS 2013 or later). No need to migrate to TFVC.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2015 supports and hosts Git repositories as well as TFVC. If you add a Git repo to your Team Project you can just add it as an additional remote and push. This will bring all history as is with no need to mess with history.

If you have to move from Git to TFVC (not recommended as Git is far better) then you can use Git-TF to push code between the two.

http://nkdagility.com/migrating-codeplex-github/

Above is a reverse example, but you should be able to:

1. Clone the correct folder in TFVC
2. Force push from your existing Git repo unto the TFVC  linked one
3. Push to TFVC

As TFVC is auditable there is no way to get around the date issue.

**Ok, so i lied and there is a way.**

1. Create a new empty Collection
2. Create a Team project and do NOT check in
3. Use the API to import each changeset and date should be writable.

...this was allowed to support a VSS to TFVC migration and your millage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have managed to get the success result. I used TFS API for modify the changeset message. It was more accessible in my situation